# How to surpress 00 padding at the end of resource only dll, after linker stage

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, linker

I'm trying to build a data only dll with MSVC 2008. There is only one structure in the source file.

I'm building the object file with the following flags (/c /TC), and linking it with (/NODEFAULTLIB /NOENTRY /DLL).

I am seeing an extra 0x18c bytes of 00s added to the end, bringing the total size of the data section to be 0x200. Is this some sort of alignment or packing issue? I am currently using a pragma pack on my structure.

How would I suppress the generation of those extra 00s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the size of the sections in the executable image (like .data) must be a power of 2 with 512 as the minimum size.  [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SectionAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value.

Simple workarounds are embedding the structure size as a field in the structure and/or the *sizeof* operator.  Or using the resource compiler and SizeofResource().

Comment: Yup, looks like that was it. The default alignment size was much larger than I was expecting, but that looks like it did it. Thanks!